# Websocket server.run() don't allow followed codes to start

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I have the following web socket server code from [GitHub](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket):

```
public class WebsocketServer extends WebSocketServer {

    private static int PORT = 2005;

    private Set<WebSocket> conns;

    public WebsocketServer() {
        super(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
        conns = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake) {
        conns.add(conn);
        System.out.println("New connection from " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
        conns.remove(conn);
        System.out.println("Closed connection to " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + message);

        for (WebSocket sock : conns) {
            sock.send(messageToSend);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (conn != null) {
            conns.remove(conn);
            // do some thing if required
        }
        System.out.println("ERROR from " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebsocketServer server = new WebsocketServer();
        server.run();

        BufferedReader sysin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            String in = sysin.readLine();
            server.sendToAll(in);
            if (in.equals("exit")) {
                server.stop();
                break;
            } else if (in.equals("restart")) {
                server.stop();
                server.start();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public void sendToAll(String text) {
        Collection<WebSocket> con = connections();
        synchronized (con) {
            for (WebSocket c : con) {
                c.send(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code work `fine, but all code that come after server.run();` won't start/work! In that part, I need to send messages from the Java console to the client.

What I am doing wrong?

**Note:** My client works in JavaScript and can connect to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `start()` `Runnable` class, **not** `run()` it directly

```
server.start();
```

instead of

```
server.run();
```

Comment: You need to `start` a *thread.* `Runnable` is *not* a class, and it doesn't have a `start()` method.